# Как создать большое поле для ввода текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как создать большое поле для ввода текста в tkinter?

Вот например:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(window) # Но там только 1 строчка!!!
e.pack() # Но там только 1 строчка!!!

window.mainlooop()
```

Как сделать многострочное текстовое поле в tkinter и получать с него введенный текст?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я сделал правку, которая это исправляет. Она на проверке

Comment: Правка успешно проверена и принята

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `tkinter.Text`.

Например:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def get_text(event=None):
    text = text_widjet.get("1.0", END)
    label_text.config(text=text)

text_widjet = tk.Text(window)
text_widjet.pack()

label_text = tk.Label(window)
label_text.pack()

Button('Вывести текст в Label', command = get_text).pack()

window.mainloop()
```